# Vault Client communication when TLS is enabled

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I setup a vault servr (not in dev mode) with keystore following the section of the link - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/single/spring-cloud-vault.html

I am able to start the server now with tls enabled. My question is simple how do I get vault client to communicate with the server.

Vault has authbackend to validate against role using TLS, but to reach to this point i think i would have to first make client connection. Can someone please throw some light.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any exceptions?

Comment: I was using the same provided in spring cloud vault master but my vault server is on different machine not local host running on vagrant. So i guess i will have to regenerate the certificates and place in the resources folder to map to the  classpath